# VBA for text to date

Tags: excel, vba, date

How to apply for all items below E4 and F4,G4,H4 and I4:
The format as seen was has a mixture of "21-07-21" and "8/2/2022" format. Due to text file to excel split using "|" the end result is the mix format of date and text:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(E2,2)+100,MID(E2,4,2),LEFT(E2,2))
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data using https://excelguru.ca/power-query-errors-please-rebuild-this-data-combination/ - also reading [repro] could help to improve your question.

Comment: This usually occurs because you have **Open**'d a txt or csv file where the date format does not match your windows regional settings.  Both forms of dates will be wrong. Better solution is to properly **Import** the file so Excel can know the incoming date format and translate it properly.  Or you can just specify the date format when you run the `text-to-columns` wizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, use the next function:

```
Function convStrToDate(strD As String) As Date
    If InStr(strD, "-") > 0 Then strD = Replace(strD, "-", "/")
    Dim arrD: arrD = Split(strD, "/")
    If UBound(arrD) = 2 Then
        convStrToDate = DateSerial(CLng(arrD(2)), CLng(arrD(1)), CLng(arrD(0)))
    Else
        MsgBox "String different than necessary pattern..."
    End If
End Function
```

It can be tested in the next way:

```
Sub TestConvStrToD()
   Debug.Print convStrToDate("21-07-21")
   Debug.Print convStrToDate("8/2/2022")
End Sub
```

The above solution assumes that "8/2/2022" means eight of February...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to distinguish two formats:

```
21-07-21
8/2/2022
```

First, let's be really sure that the second one means "The eigth of February" and not "The second of august".
In order to distinguish, you can simply use an `InStr` function to check if the date contains a slash or a hyphen. In case of a hyphen, it's the first format. In case of a slash, it's the second.

Once you have determined the format, the rest is quite easy (pseudo-code):

1. Locate the separator and take all the digits before that location, that's the day.
2. Remove the day and the separator.
3. Locate the separator and take all the digits before that location, that's the month.
4. Remove the month and the separator.
5. The rest is the year.

You follow this procedure and this is what you get for your examples:

Example "21-07-21":

```
temp="21-07-21"
```

1. Location=3, day=21
2. temp="07-21"
3. Location=3, month=07
4. temp="21"
5. year=21 (convert this into 2021)

Example "8/2/2022"

```
temp="8/2/2022"
```

1. Location=2, day=8
2. temp="2/2022"
3. Location=2, month=2
4. temp="2022"
5. year=2022

I advise you to write a UDF (User-Defined Function) for this: putting all this in a formula might make your formula too complex and unreadable.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

> Due to text file to excel split using "|" the end result is the mix
> format of date and text

**It's worth pointing out here, that Text-to-columns allows you to select the incoming date format and outputted data type etc. in the options, which would negate the need to convert these dates if done properly.**

However, to answer your question - I think you're after something like this:

```
Sub test()
    With ActiveSheet
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each c In .Range("E2:I" & lastrow)
            c.Value = DateSerial(Val(Right(c.Value, 2)), Val(Mid(c.Value, 4, 2)), Val(Left(c.Value, 2)))
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I now understand what you're doing, but when the date is somewhere in the 20th century, the idea of adding 2000 to the last two characters might prove dangerous: according to you, I would be born in 2072 :-)

Comment: I've just removed the `+2000` and the `DateSerial` function works fine without it.